# JMSTranslationBundle as a standalone symfony console application?

Tags: symfony, console, jms, bundle, translation

I am currently trying to use the `JMSTranslationBundle` as a standalone application. Is this possible? Or as alternative how do I load a [`services.xml`](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.xml) so that I don't have to construct every dependency by hand.

Comment: If you check the requirements of the Bundle (either inside the composer.json inside the bundle or at https://packagist.org/packages/jms/translation-bundle), you can see that it has some requirements. Especially the "symfony/framework-bundle" answers your question with "not easily".

Comment: What is your overall goal? To have a script that creates languagefiles out of php code?